# For- looping in smarty

Tags: php, mobile, smarty

I wrote a simple pagination code in php, but I want to display for loop in index.tpl not in index.php
what can I do ?

link for some help : http://www.smarty.net/syntax_comparison

```
$perPage = 10;
$PaginationSql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('ID') FROM VA_VIDEOS");
$Pages = ceil(mysql_result($PaginationSql, 0) / $perPage);
$Page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$Start = ($Page - 1) * $perPage;
$postDate = date("d-m-Y");
srand(time());
$randomNum = (rand()%20);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM VA_VIDEOS ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT ".$Start.", ".$perPage."");
while ($Videos = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{

$ShowVideos[] = $Videos;

}
if($Page >= 1 && $Page<=$Pages){
echo "<div style='margin-left:20px;'>";
if($Page != 1){print "<b class='pagination'><a href='?page=1'>First</a></b>";}

    for($x=1; $x<=$Pages; $x++){
    $PaginationNum = ($x == $Page) ? "<b class='page-in'>".$x."</b>" : "<a href='?page=".$x."' class='pagination'>".$x."</a>";
    echo $PaginationNum;

    }

    if($Page != $Pages){
$LastPage = "<b class='pagination'><a href='?page=".$Pages."'>Last</a></b>";
echo $LastPage;
}
echo "</div>";
} else {

    print "Error!";

}
```

Comment: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl

Comment: What is php question doing in iPhone section? Tagged by mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Just throw the last part of your script where you echo stuff into `index.tpl`.

Try something like this (uses Smarty3 foreach syntax):

```
<?php
// index.php

$perPage = 10;
// ...
while ($Videos = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $ShowVideos[] = $Videos;
}

$smarty->assign('current_page', $Page);
$smarty->assign('pages', range($pages)); // returns: array(1, 2, 3, ..., $Pages)
```

index.tpl

```
{if $current_page < $pages|count}
    <b class="pagination"><a href="?page=1">First</a></b>
{/if}

{foreach $pages as $page}
    {if $page == $current_page}
         <b class="page-in">{$page}</b>
    {else}
        <a href="?page={$page}" class="pagination">{$page}</a>

    {/if}
{/foreach}

{if $page < $pages|count}
    <b class="pagination"><a href="?page={$pages|count}">Last</a></b>
{/if}
```

For extra performance calculate the size of `$pages` in `index.php` and assign it. I was just trying to show how to use PHP functions as a [variable modifier](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifiers.tpl) in case you need it.

Answer (score 0):

use loop like this

```
while ($Videos = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{

$ShowVideos[] = $Videos;

}
$smarty->assign("video", $ShowVideos);
```

The TPL file would look like this :

```
{section name=video loop=$video}

<li>{$video[video].id}</li> //// will show the video id from database


{/section}
```